# Need help with @Restresource

Tags: apex, rest-api

all, need help with below class. I want to insert multiple leads but currently this class accepts only 1 lead. How can I send multiple JSON list to this class? Does Rest API support multiple inserts? How can I optimize this code??

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/createleads/*')

global with sharing  class createleads_V1 {

    @HttpPost
global static LeadInWrapper doPost(LeadInWrapper[] leads) {

            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        LeadInWrapper response = new LeadInWrapper ();


        List<Lead> leadsToInsert = new List<Lead>();
        for(LeadInWrapper leadWrapper : leads){
            Lead l = new Lead ();
            l.FirstName= leadWrapper.FirstName;
            l.LastName= leadWrapper.LastName;
            l.Company_Name__c = leadWrapper.Company;                                 
            l.Street = leadWrapper.Street;
            l.City= leadWrapper.City;
            l.State= leadWrapper.State;
            l.Postalcode= leadWrapper.Postalcode;
            l.Country= leadWrapper.Country;
            l.LeadSource = leadWrapper.LeadSource; 
            l.OwnerId = '0055B000000FGkw';
            l.Email = leadWrapper.Email;
            l.Phone = leadWrapper.Phone ;

            leadsToInsert.add(l);
        }

        insert leadsToInsert;

            response.status = 'Success';
        response.StatusCode = 201;

        response.message = 'successful.';
        return response;

}    
    global class LeadInWrapper {
        public String status;
        public String message;
        public integer StatusCode;
         public String FirstName;
        public String LastName;
        public String Company;
        public String Street;
        public String City;
        public String State;
        public String Postalcode;
        public String Country;
        public String Email;
        public String Phone;
        public String LeadSource;


    }


}
```

Code works fine with 1 lead but When I try to insert two Leads with JSON below, it fails with this error:

> [   {
>       "message": "Extra JSON in request found after deserialization at: [line:15, column:3]",
>       "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"   } ]

JSON i`m trying to pass:

```
    {
"FirstName" : "Test name 1",
"LastName" : "Test name 2",
"Company" : "test company",
"Street" : "Abc street",
"City" : "somecity",
"State" : "somestate",
"Postalcode" : "1111",
"Country" : "United States",
"Email" : "name.test@test.com"
},
{
"FirstName" : "Test name 1",
"LastName" : "Test name 2",
"Company" : "test company",
"Street" : "Abc street",
"City" : "somecity",
"State" : "somestate",
"Postalcode" : "1111",
"Country" : "United States",
"Email" : "name.test@test.com"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper class and an array of this new class as parameter of your `doPost` method as below:

**Wrapper**

```
global class LeadInWrapper {
        public String FirstName;
        public String LastName;
        public String Company;
        public String Street;
        public String City;
        public String State;
        public String Postalcode;
        public String Country;
        public String Email;
        public String Phone;
        public String LeadSource;
    }
```

**Method**

```
global static LeadWrapper doPost(LeadInWrapper[] leads) {
        List<Lead> leadsToInsert = new List<Lead>();
        for(LeadInWrapper leadWrapper : leads){
            Lead l = new Lead ();
            l.FirstName= leadWrapper.FirstName;
            l.LastName= leadWrapper.LastName;
            l.Company_Name__c = leadWrapper.Company;                                 
            l.Street = leadWrapper.Street;
            l.City= leadWrapper.City;
            l.State= leadWrapper.State;
            l.Postalcode= leadWrapper.Postalcode;
            l.Country= leadWrapper.Country;
            l.LeadSource = leadWrapper.LeadSource; 
            l.OwnerId = '0055B000000FGkw';
            l.Email = leadWrapper.Email;
            l.Phone = leadWrapper.Phone ;

            leadsToInsert.add(l);
        }

        insert leadsToInsert;
```

**Json to pass**

```
    {
   "leads":[
      {
         "FirstName":"Test name 1",
         "LastName":"Test name 2",
         "Company":"test company",
         "Street":"Abc street",
         "City":"somecity",
         "State":"somestate",
         "Postalcode":"1111",
         "Country":"United States",
         "Email":"name.test@test.com"
      },
      {
         "FirstName":"Test name 1",
         "LastName":"Test name 2",
         "Company":"test company",
         "Street":"Abc street",
         "City":"somecity",
         "State":"somestate",
         "Postalcode":"1111",
         "Country":"United States",
         "Email":"name.test@test.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, I update the code but still getting below error (see updated code above). Can you point out what is not correct?

Error:
[
  {
    "message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: FirstName at [line:2, column:16]",
    "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
  }
]

Comment: I updated my answer with the json to pass to your method.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help !